# No 'changes' key for replacing the same document in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I am replacing one of my documents with a document that happens to be exactly the same as the one which is already saved in the database. I am doing `replace` with `return_values=True` and I expect that the result would contain a `changes` key. But what I get back after the operation is:

```
{u'skipped': 0, u'deleted': 0, u'unchanged': 1, u'errors': 0, u'replaced': 0, u'inserted': 0}
```

I would have expected to get back that key together with the old and new values, which would be the same.

I know my wanted behavior worked at a previous point, but when did it change? And how can I have the old behavior again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour was changed in RethinkDB 2.0. There is a proposal for making the old behaviour available:

https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4068